# Physical authentication alternative in android

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication

My client want to make sure that his marketers meet some of their specific clients on a regular basis. I had thought of that this could be possible by getting the clients fingerprints. But as I read in several pages, the fingerprint api is available in android api 23+ and in Samsung devices it is not possible to check the fingerprints of people other than the phone owner.

Is there any alternatives that one can use for physical authentication (not like password)?

I want to aim as many devices possible and as lower android api level possible. 
I also have the option to authenticate on server side based on information received from the device (if there are ways to do it that is not possible by the device itself)

**Note:**
It looks like that you get strange ideas of my question. although it is not related but let me explain to clear things:

In our country each factory has its own marketers that visit markets on regular basis (daily, weekly, monthly,...) based on their product (milk, biscuit, chips, bread, juice, ....), while the factory wants their marketers visit every markets (as they'll loose their shares to their competitives) marketers think differently (as they receive a small percent of their sale), they just visit those markets which will buy for example a thousand of apple juice and skip those who will buy only 10 (which for them the percentage they get doesn't cover the gas money) and when factory calls this markets to see why they were not buying their products anymore, they get to know that their marketers has not visited them for months.

This is the way they want to make sure that their marketers visit every market and not only the good buyers.

Comment: If a "marketer" from your client asked me to provide "physical authentication", your client would no longer be welcome at my firm. I also suggest that you consult with your attorney before continuing work with this client, to make sure that you are not exposing yourself to civil or criminal liability. Beyond that, there are no options in Android itself for physical authentication of arbitrary people. You would need to look into third-party libraries and services.

Comment: I think you get it wrong. those clients want that marketers visit them (and provide the goods they need). the problem is that some marketers skip the small buyers telling their boss that they couldn't sell to them and this upsets both the firm owner (the boss) and his clients. (the clients are markets by the way)

Comment: to avoid confusion I added a note that why this system is needed.

Comment: Collecting fingerprints has serious privacy ramifications. This is why, for example, you cannot extract fingerprint data from an Android device via some API. So, I stand by my statement: if your marketer demanded that I provide a fingerprint as part of a sales call, your client would no longer be welcome in my firm. Your client would be welcome to call me, if I had not placed an order in a while, to see if your marketer has been visiting my firm, without causing nearly as many privacy issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is strange, but anyway: You can use (GPS tagged) photo of client, or/and his sign (by stilus on mobile device screen).

Comment: to avoid confusion I added a note that why this system is needed.

Comment: we already use gps but one may pass by a market without visiting it.

Comment: "but one may pass by a market" - for avoid this: (GPS tagged) photo of client and his sign.